It seems my contract isn't deploying correctly
I have been trying to test my smart contract and this is what I keep getting:

address undefined

Console command and output:
 C:\Users\HP-PC\Desktop\dapp\My Dappazon\dappazon> npx hardhat test


  Dappazon
    Deployment
Contract Address: undefined
      ✔ Sets the owner
    Listing
Contract Address: undefined
      ✔ Returns items attributes
Contract Address: undefined
      ✔ Emits List event
    Buying
Contract Address: undefined
      ✔ Updates buyer order count
Contract Address: undefined
      ✔ Adds order to user
Contract Address: undefined
Contract Address: undefined
      1) Updates the contract balance


  5 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Dappazon
       Buying
         Updates the contract balance:
     TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.12.0)
      at makeError (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:687:21)
      at assert (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:715:25)
      at assertArgument (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:727:5)
      at resolveAddress (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\address\checks.ts:122:19)
      at HardhatEthersProvider._getAddress (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\hardhat-ethers-provider.ts:437:26)
      at HardhatEthersProvider.getBalance (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\hardhat-ethers-provider.ts:124:40)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\Dappazon.js:90:50)

Code:
const { expect } = require("chai")

const tokens = (n) => {
  return ethers.parseUnits(n.toString(), 'ether')
}

// Global constants for listing an item...
const ID = 1
const NAME = "Shoes"
const CATEGORY = "Clothing"
const IMAGE = "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTYEboq8raiBs7GTUg2yLXB3PMz6HuBNgNfSZBx5Msztg/shoes.jpg"
const COST = tokens(1)
const RATING = 4
const STOCK = 5

describe("Dappazon", () => {
    let dappazon
    let deployer, buyer

    beforeEach(async () => {
        //Setup Account
        [deployer, buyer] = await ethers.getSigners()

        //Deploy contract
        const Dappazon = await ethers.getContractFactory("Dappazon")
        dappazon = await Dappazon.deploy()
        console.log("Contract Address:", dappazon.address); // Debug log
    })

    describe("Deployment", () => {
        it("Sets the owner", async () => {
            expect(await dappazon.owner()).to.equal(deployer.address)
        })
    })

    describe("Listing", () => {
        let transaction

        beforeEach(async () => {
            //List item
            transaction = await dappazon.connect(deployer).list(ID, NAME, CATEGORY, IMAGE, COST, RATING, STOCK)
            await transaction.wait()
        })

        it("Returns items attributes", async () => {
            const item = await dappazon.items(ID)

            expect(item.id).to.equal(ID)
            expect(item.name).to.equal(NAME)
            expect(item.category).to.equal(CATEGORY)
            expect(item.image).to.equal(IMAGE)
            expect(item.cost).to.equal(COST)
            expect(item.rating).to.equal(RATING)
            expect(item.stock).to.equal(STOCK)
        })

        it("Emits List event", () => {
            expect(transaction).to.emit(dappazon, "List")
        })
    })

    describe("Buying", () => {
        let transaction

        beforeEach(async () => {
            // List an item
            transaction = await dappazon.connect(deployer).list(ID, NAME, CATEGORY, IMAGE, COST, RATING, STOCK)
            await transaction.wait()

            // Buy an item
            transaction = await dappazon.connect(buyer).buy(ID, { value: COST })
            await transaction.wait()
        })

        it("Updates buyer order count", async () => {
            const result = await dappazon.orderCount(buyer.address)
            expect(result).to.equal(1)
        })

        it("Adds order to user", async () => {
            const order = await dappazon.orders(buyer.address, 1) 
            
            expect(order.time).to.be.greaterThan(0)
            expect(order.item.name).to.equal(NAME)
        })

        it("Updates the contract balance", async () => {
            console.log("Contract Address:", dappazon.address); // Debug log
            const result = await ethers.provider.getBalance(dappazon.address)
            console.log("Contract Balance:", result.toString()); // Debug log
            expect(result).to.equal(COST)
        })
    })
})


I don't know exactly what to try, I don't seem to understand why the contract is not deploying the address when testing my smart contract.
I am on a Windows platform.

please what exactly do you mean....I have been trying to test my smart contract and i keep getting undefined when i trying to console.log my smart contract address

but do you know any possible reasons for a contract to display undefined and is it something that can be fixed, thank you alot for your time by the way really appreciate
